A Plastic inside a silver cup of Kiddush and Havdalah
Is it permissible to put a plastic cup (disposable) inside a silver cup in Kiddush and Havdalah? The disposable cup is filled with the amount of the appropriate shiur (amount). However, it protrudes above the silver cup (it also starts a little above the bottom). Should the plastic cup be filled to its maximum or up to the height of the silver cup? Is there a difference between Kiddush to Havadla?
